# How to use .erase() in while loop?

Tags: c++

background:
This is program to add 1 to a number stored digit by digit in a vector.

Numbers having 0 in front are allowed as input but not as output.
eg: 0123 & 123 are both valid input 
    but 0124 is a invalid output 
    while 124 is an valid output

problem:
I want to use `erase()` to delete 0's in front of the output vector till an non zero value is found using the while loop at the bottom of the code. 
However the compiler returns a garbage value. another online compiler gives a segmentation fault.
Rest of the code works fine when compiled without the while loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> A = { 9, 9, 9 };
    A.insert(A.begin(), 0); /*--last carry may nonzero so new digit -*/
    vector<int>::reverse_iterator it;
    int c = 1;
    for (it = A.rbegin(); it != A.rend(); it++) /*----finds and adds carry---*/
    {
        int d = *it;
        d = d + c;
        c = d / 10;
        if (c == 0)
            *it = d;
        else
        {
            d = d % 10;
            *it = d;
        }

    }
    vector<int>::iterator iss;
    iss = A.begin();
```

Problem loop starts

```
    while (*iss == 0) /*----------------problem----------------*/
    {
        iss = A.erase(iss);
    }
```

loop Ends

```
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << A[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This program looks correct to me and works for me. You get unexpected output or crashes on exactly the program pasted here? Can you be more specific about the "garbage value"?

Comment: Unrelated: Research the Erase-remove idiom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written is almost right. There should be an additional check for the end iterator.

```
while(iss != A.end() && *iss == 0) {
    iss = A.erase(iss);
}
```

However, it is possible to implement it so that the algorithm has better performance:

```
while(iss != A.end() && *iss == 0) {
    ++iss;
}
A.erase(A.begin(), iss);
```

Comment: A useful precaution, but doesn't explain any issues with the given program, since it will definitely not have `A` empty or containing only zeros.

Comment: @aschepler Let me quote myself: "What you've written is almost right. There should be an additional check for the end iterator.". The lack of checking for the end iterator is the issue. Nothing of what I wrote is there in case A is empty or contains only zeroes. However those cases are also handled properly.

Comment: Yes, your code is better and safer _in general_. But _in the program as pasted_, the `while (*iss == 0) { iss = A.erase(); }` will not cause any problems, because it turns out `A.size() == 4 && *A.begin() == 1`, so the `while` loop does nothing but one valid dereference and comparison.

Comment: Agree. A potential error, but the code provided by Asker will not trigger it.

Comment: what you have written along with placing A.insert(A.begin() , 0) before the !st for loop solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Not obvious where exactly you see garbage, but you miss a check if the iterator is valid, e.g. `while(iss != A.end() && *iss==0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of erasing item from a vector, it is almost always preferable (from a complexity point of view) to move items to preserve to another vector, move the objects to keep to another vector. This has also better performance (erasing from the head of the vector will move all other objects in the best case):

```
void remove_zeroes(std::vector<int>& v) {
    std::vector<int> saved;
    auto begin = std::find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[](int x){ return x != 0; });
    for(auto it = begin; it != v.end(); it++) {
        saved.push_back(std::move(*it));
    }
    v.swap(saved);
}
```

Although in this case it is equivalent to just use the range erase method of `std::vector`, which takes two iterators as parameters (as suggested in other answer) this technique might be useful if the elements to remove aren't in a contiguous range.